# Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return variant or object error

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I've been developing a program in excel vba for some time now with no errors. Today however, adter only commenting out something outside of a sub, all of my functions now throw a `Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return variant or object error` error. See a sample below:

```
Public Function fGetEmployees() As Variant()

Dim oDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim oCM As ADODB.Command
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo Err:

strSQL = "SELECT StaffId, FirstName, LastName " & _
        "FROM ptqEmployees"

Set oDB = New ADODB.Connection
oDB.Open gcConn
Set oCM = New ADODB.Command

With oCM
    .ActiveConnection = oDB
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    Set oRS = .Execute
End With

fGetEmployees = oRS.GetRows()

oRS.Close
Set oRS = Nothing
oDB.Close
Set oRS = Nothing

Exit Function

Err:
    Call fLogDBError(Err.Number, Err.Description, 4)

End Function
```

The error gets thrown on line:
`fGetEmployees = oRS.GetRows()`

As said this has been functioning with no issues for sometime now. There's no option to debug either.

Can anyone assist with what the issue is?

Comment: change `Function fGetEmployees() As Variant()` to `Function fGetEmployees() As Variant`

Comment: @simoco Thanks, I now get the error `Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property`. I've gone through and checked the whole module and there's definitely no comments out of place

Comment: `oRS.GetRows()` should be `oRS.GetRows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange but I exported the module and then imported it and it's working fine now.